# How to sort alphabetically with a form select using pluck.all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pluck

I have a form and there's a drop down to choose dance styles however, this list is not in alphabetical order.

My form for the select is:

```
<%= f.label "Dance Style", class: "form-label" %>
<%= f.select :dance_styles_id_in, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id), { scope: :sorted, :include_blank => "All dance styles" }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", placeholder: "Any dance style", multiple: true } %>
```

I also tried:

```
<%= f.label "Dance Style", class: "form-label" %>
<%= f.select :dance_styles_id_in, DanceStyle.all.pluck(:name, :id).order(name: :asc), { :include_blank => "All dance styles" }, { class: "form-select", id: "select-dancestyle", placeholder: "Any dance style", multiple: true } %>
```

I tried to add the scope connected to my `dance_style.rb` model where I am sorting with the following but not 100% sure about syntax, but it works in the rails console:

```rb
scope :sorted, -> { DanceStyle.order(name: :asc) }
```

How would I pull this scope into my form? I feel I'm missing something simple and my Google searches haven't been helping...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach with the scope seems a good idea, as you can eventually re-use it in other places. You can simplify it a bit:

```rb
scope :sorted, -> { order(name: :asc) }
```

And then in your views:

```
<%= f.select :dance_styles_id_in, options_for_select(DanceStyle.sorted.pluck(:name, :id)), ... %>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I implemented this for the rest of my models where I have collection selects throughout my app! 

Answer (score 2):

Can not `order` after `pluck` because `pluck` returns an `array`, and `order` using after `ActiveRecord_Relation`.
So let's try to change:

```
DanceStyle.select(:name, :id).order(name: :asc)
```